# Parse Cloud Code Ending Prematurely?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm writing a job that I want to run every hour in the background on Parse. My database has two tables. The first contains a list of `Question`s, while the second lists all of the user\question agreement pairs (`QuestionAgreement`s). Originally my plan was just to have the client count the `QuestionAgreement`s itself, but I'm finding that this results in a lot of requests that really could be done away with, so I want this background job to run the count, and then update a field directly on `Question` with it.

Here's my attempt:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("updateQuestionAgreementCounts", function(request, status) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var query = new Parse.Query("Question");
    query.each(function(question) {
        var agreementQuery = new Parse.Query("QuestionAgreement");
        agreementQuery.equalTo("question", question);
        agreementQuery.count({
            success: function(count) {
                question.set("agreementCount", count);
                question.save(null, null);
            }
        });
    }).then(function() {
        status.success("Finished updating Question Agreement Counts.");
    }, function(error) {
        status.error("Failed to update Question Agreement Counts.")
    });
});
```

The problem is, this only seems to be running on a few of the `Question`s, and then it stops, appearing in the Job Status section of the Parse Dashboard as "succeeded". I suspect the problem is that it's returning prematurely. Here are my questions:

1 - How can I keep this from returning prematurely? (Assuming this is, in fact, my problem.)

2 - What is the best way of debugging cloud code? Since this isn't client side, I don't have any way to set breakpoints or anything, do I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to utilize promises, as suggested by knshn, to make it so that my code would complete before running success.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("updateQuestionAgreementCounts", function(request, status) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var promises = [];  // Set up a list that will hold the promises being waited on.
    var query = new Parse.Query("Question");
    query.each(function(question) {
        var agreementQuery = new Parse.Query("QuestionAgreement");
        agreementQuery.equalTo("question", question);
        agreementQuery.equalTo("agreement", 1);

        // Make sure that the count finishes running first!
        promises.push(agreementQuery.count().then(function(count) {
            question.set("agreementCount", count);

            // Make sure that the object is actually saved first!
            promises.push(question.save(null, null));
        }));
    }).then(function() {
        // Before exiting, make sure all the promises have been fulfilled!
        Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function() {
            status.success("Finished updating Question Agreement Counts.");
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`status.success` is called before the asynchronous success calls of `count` are finished. To prevent this, you can use promises here. Check the docs for [Parse.Query.each](http://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html#each).

> Iterates over each result of a query, calling a callback for each one. If the callback returns a promise, the iteration will not continue until that promise has been fulfilled.

So, you can chain the `count` promise:

```
agreementQuery.count().then(function () {
    question.set("agreementCount", count);
    question.save(null, null);
});
```

You can also use [parallel promises](https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide#promises-parallel) to make it more efficient.

There are no breakpoints in cloud code, that makes Parse really hard to use. Only way is logging your variables with `console.log`

Comment: Great, thanks! I'll look into this then accept your answer once I see that it works this evening.

Comment: Your answer gave me a useful start so I'll +1 it, but there were too many pieces missing from it for me to mark it as accepted.

Comment: good that you figure out you need an array to keep parallel promises. without parallel promoises, you could also return `agreementQuery.count().then(function () {})` inside `query.each` as the docs say the iteration will not continue until that promise has been fulfilled